# About Apache storm, can one batch in Trident topology be processed on several workers paralle?

Tags: apache-storm, trident

I want one batch can be processed on different servers, how can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A batch is a "unit of work" and cannot be divided. Thus, it is not possible to process a batch on multiple workers in parallel.

(Of course, you can sent a batch to all downstream executors via "allGrouping" but the each executor will process the same data, ie, I guess that is not what you want.)